# p/react: cannot access state when using "tag" syntax

Tags: reactjs, react-props, preact

I'm teaching myself p/react, and I'm unsure why I cannot access a component's state.

I have a component:

```
const AView = (state,props) => (
  <div>
    <p>{state.a}</p>
    <B />
  </div>
)

class A extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { a: 1 };
  }
  render(props,state) {
    return <AView a={state.a}/>
  }
}

const BView = (state,props) => (
  <div>
    <p>{state.b}</p>
  </div>
)

class B extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { b: 2 };
  }
  render(props,state) {
    return <BView b={state.b}/>
  }
}
```

This renders component `A` with the expected state `1`, but it does not render component `B` with state `2` (component `B` is just render with empty `<p>` tags).

However, if I use an alternative syntax, I am able to render component `B` with state `2`:

```
class B extends Component {
  ...
  render(props,state) {
    return BView(props,state);
  }
}
```

Am I missing something conceptually here, or is there just some syntax I'm unaware of? I've tried googling around, but I don't really know enough terminology to get relevant search hits.

Comment: Are you rendering `<AView />` and wondering why the `<BView />` inside won't render `state.b` or something else?

Comment: @Deryck. Yes. I’m wondering why I can’t see BView state when rendering AView unless I return the BView as an explicit function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Preact. But I would try to fix it like this:

```
const AView = (props) => (
  <div>
    <p>{props.text}</p>
    <BView />
  </div>
)

class A extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { a: 1 };
  }
  render() {
    return <AView text={this.state.a} />
  }
}

const BView = (props) => (
  <div>
    <p>{props.text}</p>
  </div>
)

class B extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { b: 2 };
  }
  render() {
    return <BView text={this.state.b} />
  }
}
```

Comment: The state is indeed local to the component. But in your examples, you are trying to use state that exists in parent component. This is why you need to pass it down as props.